# using switch navigator: object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate') undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-props, navigator, onpress

I am using react native and I keep getting this error. undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate')

when I click the onPress button on my Login Page. Can anyone help?

```
 <Button
   title="Don't have an account yet? Sign up"
    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Signup")}
 />
```

// MY LOGIN PAGE //

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHnJA.png)

// MY NAV PAGE //

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1AKN.png)

Comment: the code in the screenshot looks good. I have tried the same code in expo. It works. Here is the link for it https://snack.expo.io/dkJozSSr8. Check if you are missing anything.

Comment: may be there is issue in your Signup.js page.

Comment: thanks @Sriram, I missed an import, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in you render function. Then call navigate("Signup")

```html
render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation; // add this
    return (
```